# Can I import a package installed in one virtual environment in global or another virtual environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I would like to have two versions of TensorFlow (tf) installed on my PC. Some of my programs run on tf v1 and some on tf v2. So, I can separately create two virtual environments (venv) one for tf v1 and another for tf v2, and use --use-system-packages for each venv for the other (global) package requirements for my codes. Then, I would keep my programs in the corresponding venv that has the correct tf version installed.

However, for some specific reasons, I want to be able to use both versions of TensorFlow in a global environment too (i.e. without entering / activating a venv).

**Questions**:

Is there a way where I can just install 2 versions of TensorFlow (and/or numpy) in 2 venvs, and then access either of them in a global environment, using an import statement (with the version / venv to import from specified)? If this is not possible using venvs, is there any other way around to achieve the same?

Extending the same further, suppose I am in a venv. I want to know if I can import packages that are installed in some other venv? If yes, how?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't, and, more important, you shouldn't. If you're interested in gory details why this is the case, let me know and I'll write a full answer.

Comment: @Marat Thanks, and I am interested in the details, it would be great if you could take time out to write a full answer! I have been searching and reading about it for the past 2-3 hours but couldn't get anything related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem definition:**
we need to import two different versions of a Python package. Both versions have dependencies and provide the same namespace (`tensorflow`).

**Why it is not possible:** when Python loads a module (`import tensorflow as tf`), it tries to avoid redundant work and skips modules that were loaded already.
So, it is not possible to load the same namespace from two different locations.

Few fun facts:

- You can manipulate paths where Python will look for a module at runtime. When loading a module for the first time, Python will go through a list of directoris in `sys.path`, looking for the requested namespace. Directories in `sys.path` are installation dependent, but usually go in this order: local directory, builtin modules, installed packages. The last one is a directory or a set of directories where your package manager (pip, easy_install, ...) stores installed packages. It is usually more than one location, including packages installed system-wide, user folder (e.g. `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`), and virtual environment-specific folder (e.g. `xxx.venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`). Depending on the setup, you can have any combination of these. The fun part is that you can insert new directories: `sys.path[6:6] = ['path/to/another/venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages']`. However, it won't help getting two instances of the same namespace because of caching.
- In `sys.path` folders, Python will look for a module with matching name, which represents a namespace. Python package names are often the same as the namespace they provide, but they can also be different. For example, in `pip install numpy` the last portion is a package name, but in `import numpy` it is a namespace. Roughly 1/3 of all PyPI packages' namespaces are different from the package name, for example package `intel-numpy` also provides namespace `numpy`. If you install `intel-numpy`, pip will silently overwrite the folder (and so, the content of the namespace) previously provided by `numpy`. Yep, Python package managers keep track of installed package names, but not namespaces. So, even if two versions of a package provide different namespaces, you cannot have them both. But if you have two different packages providing the same namespace, pip will be happy to install both, but will only keep the last installed.
- If two versions of the same package provide different namespaces, you can install them different virtual environments, then manipulate `sys.path` to include packages from both and get both namespaces at the same time. Not our case, though.
- Another option: repackage one version of the package, renaming the namespace. In this case, it's easier to also change the package name and install them in the same place/venv. You might even reupload this repackaged version of the package to PyPI (I've seen people doing this), but it won't work with TF and any other non-trivial packages because of the diference in dependency versions. Fun fact: Python package managers don't resolve dependency versions; if package A requires C==1.0 and B requires C==2.0, after installing A and B you will get only one version of C, crippling either A or B.

Finally, why you should not do that: it is against Python principles. Explicit is better than implicit, and manipulating library paths at runtime is not the most transparent and supportable approach. Still, the problem of maintaining a compatible set of dependencies is real, and this is why we have venv, pipenv etc.

From the language design perspective, dealing with multiple versions of the same package does have its benefits and was adopted by several languages (e.g. JS). However, it makes imports a lot more expensive. Historically, this is a niche scenario for Python community, so it doesn't outweigh the performance penalty.